# X-Men who died because of their powers

Tags: marvel, x-men, mutant, powers

Within X-Men universe have there been cases where an individual **unintentionally** died because of **technicalities** of their powers?

**Example 1:**
Mutant `X` can fly, but `X` doesn't know he can only fly in total 1 hour per day (suppose between 00:00 day 1 and 00:00 day 2). Eventually, `X` flies really high, after 1 hour his power disappears (as he's used used up his power for that day), `X` plummets down and dies.

**Example 2:**
Mutant `Y` can shoot water balls that explode. When `Y` is near a water source (suppose *near* means within a fixed radius), that source is used to create the water balls. At some point, `Y` uses his powers not within a water source and his body explodes as `Y` did not know that some liquid was required to feed his power.

Note: mutants that eventually figure out the technicalities or side-effects of their powers through usage **do not** count.

Comment: I believe there's an X-Men story where some mutants die by losing their secondary powers. For example, the mutant who can create fire loses his invulnerability to fire.

Comment: Your question is very broad, but you've tagged in with X-Men. Are you specifically asking about the Marvel universe (where the X-Men exist)? If so, that would narrow your question and likely get it reopened, if you could clarify that.

Comment: Yes, narrowing it down to X-men is fine.

Comment: In [Ruins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruins_(comics)) (not part of the main canon because it's a parody), Magneto accidentally drags every piece of metal in the vicinity toward himself. He's ultimately killed by a plane crashing into the terminal; https://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/2/28028/709132-ruins5.jpg

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for something along those lines.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In [Peter Parker: The Spectacular Spider-Man #91](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Peter_Parker,_The_Spectacular_Spider-Man_Vol_1_91) we find the mutant [**Unus the Untouchable**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unus_the_Untouchable) recuperating from a recent fight with the Hulk.

It would appear that this encounter (and the exertion of his powers) has resulted in him gaining in strength. Unfortunately, a side-effect of this newfound power is that he now can't eat or drink, gravity is losing its grip on him and ultimately he *suffocates* to death.

[image]

---

In the parody "[Ruins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruins_(comics))", the death of mutants (as a result of their own powers) is a theme that's explored in vivid detail.

- **Magneto** is killed when his magnetic harness breaks and tons of metal slam into him.

[image]

- **Mystique** is killed when her powers run out of control (warning NFSW - Gory)

> [image]

Comment: That's a parody? Geez, I'd hate to see what an intentional gore comic would look like!

Comment: Unus's suffocation was later retconned so it didn't kill him, but he ended up dying in an almost identical way anyway.

Comment: @tobiasvl - Unless Unus is Uncle Ben in disguise, there was always a possibility that he'd come back later.

Comment: @Valorum:   Unus -- Ooncle Ben -- obviously that is what's going on.